# jquery not changing the value of one input tag based on the value of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an input tag1 with class=class1 and another tag2 with class=class2. Input values are numbers. I want the value of tag2 to be changed to one half of the value of tag1 when a value in tag1 changes. The following works except when tag1 value has a comma (e.g., 1,000). I am removing the comma using regular expression but it still does not work when tag1 value is larger than 999

```
$('.class1').change(function () {    
   $('.class2').val(parseInt($('.class1').val().replace(/,/g, '')) / 2).change();
});
```

This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 app and here is an example of tag1 and tag2.:

```
@Html.TextBox("txt_Fees","",new{ @class="class1"})
@Html.TextBox("txt_HalfFees","",new{ @class="class2"})
```

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Yce2V/

Comment: working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/8LjnC/

Comment: Dividing a string by a number or using parseInt without radix can give unexpected results.

Comment: try `$('.class2').val(parseInt($('.class1').val().replace(/,/g, ''),10) / 2).change();`

Comment: Per an advice from @Dalius, I added `radix` (10) in a parseInt overload above and it's working now. Thank you for good advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restricting the fee value to numbers only, like so:

```
<input type="text" class="class1" name="txt_Fees" />
<input type="text" class="class2" name="txt_HalfFees" />


(function($){
    var $fee = $('.class1'),
        $halfFee = $('.class2'),
        numsOnly,
        handleFeeChange;

    numsOnly = function(){
        var val = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        this.value = val;
    };

    handleFeeChange = function() {
        var val = this.value;
        $halfFee.val(val / 2);
    };

    $(function(){
        $fee
        .on('keydown keyup', numsOnly)
        .on('change', handleFeeChange);
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/m7J3e/4/

Comment: the client wants the numbers to display in money format (e.g. 1,500 etc.). I just added radix 10 in a parseInt overload per an advice from Dalius above in my example above and it worked. I am already forcing the users to enter numbers only in the money/number fields.